# UINavigationBar subclass pushing and popping methods not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uikit, uinavigationbar

I'm subclassing UINavigationBar because I need iOS 7 appearance all the way to iOS 5.

I've overridden the following methods:

```
- (void)pushNavigationItem:(UINavigationItem *)item animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog(@"pushNavigationItem:animated:");
    [super pushNavigationItem:item animated:animated];

    _titleView = item.titleView;
}

- (UINavigationItem *)popNavigationItemAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog(@"popNavigationItemAnimated:");
    return [super popNavigationItemAnimated:animated];
}
```

But they're never called (no output to console, and no interruption on breakpoints).

Everything else, including drawRect: and layoutSubviews works fine.

Am I doing something wrong or is it some bug in UIKit?

Comment: @Ian unfortunately no.

Comment: in my case, I figured out that (I believe) the native back button calls `popNavigationItemAnimated:`, which in turn calls `popViewControllerAnimated:`. I had replaced the native back button with a custom one, and my own action that called `popViewControllerAnimated:` directly, and therefore skipped `popNavigationItemAnimated:`. Unfortunately, you get an inconsistency error if you try to call `popNavigationItemAnimated:` instead of `popViewControllerAnimated:`, so I had to find a solution that did not involve `popNavigationItemAnimated:`.

Comment: Same issue here, though I'd expect `-[setItems:]` to be called at some point too. Once the new view loads the navigation items are indeed set as expected.

Comment: @KenM.Haggerty I just tested this, and setItems is never called from pushNavigationItem or popNavigationItem.